# How to make remove a map pin after a certain amount of time has passed using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I have a pin on a map that I would like to be removed after a certain amount of time has passed. I have implemented all proper protocols to place the annotation. Just not sure where to have something that checks if the value for the time variable is `>=` a certain amount.

```
var timer = NSTimer()

let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

var time = 0
```

//button press creates a pin

```
@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

        func timerFunc() {

            time++

        }

        annotation.coordinate = location

        annotation.title = "Place"

        annotation.subtitle = "Description"

        map.addAnnotation(annotation)

            timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("timerFunc"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        }

        if time >= 5 {
            timer.invalidate()
        } 

    }
```

Now it seems I would need to place something like this somewhere:

```
if time >= 5 {
    map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use NSTimer to call a method which removes annotation.

```
var myTimer: NSTimer!


@IBAction func buttonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    annotation.coordinate = location
    annotation.title = "Place"
    annotation.subtitle = "Description"
    map.addAnnotation(annotation)
    myTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5, target: self, selector: "runTimedCode", userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
}

//this method will be called after 5 seconds
func runTimedCode() {  
       map.removeAnnotation(annotation)
}
```